# How to retrieve values from Queue using for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, queue

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Queue ar = new Queue();

            ar.Enqueue(45);
            ar.Enqueue(23);
            ar.Enqueue(2);
            ar.Enqueue(87);

            foreach (int x in ar)
            {    
                Console.Write("{0}  ", x);
            }                 
            Console.ReadLine();   
       }
    }
```

I know how to retrieve values from a queue using foreach loop. but May I know it is possible to  do same thing with the help of for loop ?

I tried following code. but **ar[i]** is not a valid code. what is the suitable code for **ar[i]** ?

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < ar.count ; i++) {

         Console.Write("{0}  ", ar[i]);

}
```

Comment: `ar.Dequeue()` will go in place of `ar[i]`. But why..? If foreach works, use it. Btw use generic `Queue<T>` not `Queue`, that way you can avoid boxing.

Comment: A queue doesn't have an indexer. If it did, it wouldn't be a queue.

Comment: If you need the index in your `foreach` just create a `int index = 0;` before the loop  and `index++;` at the end of the loop.  Or consider using a `List` instead as a `Queue` isn't meant to be indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to use a `for`-loop for a `Queue` since it's not a collection with an index(like `IList<T>`). So you cannot access items randomly (as with an array: `ar[0]`). You can use [`Queue<T>.Dequeue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the first and remove it or use [`Queue<T>.Peek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz28y5c(v=vs.110).aspx) to return the first without removing it.

If you used a for-loop you would even get an expected behaviour:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.Count; i++)
     Console.Write("{0}  ", ar.Dequeue());
```

Does this display and show all 4 items? No, only the first two because `Queue.Count` decreases dynamically in the loop whereas the counter variable `i` increases, hence the loop stops at 2.

So a `for`-loop is simply the wrong type of loop for this collection. A `while` is more appropriate:

```
while(ar.Count > 0)
    Console.Write("{0}  ", ar.Dequeue());
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Schmelter for your explanation.. You solved my all problems.